# How to salvage a gigantic, possibly corrupt, AIFF file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, quicktime, vlc, transcoding

Due to a Sound Track Pro glitch, I have a problematic AIF file.  **It plays fine in QuickTime Player, and is about 1 hour 50 mins long.**  However:

- It's 3.81GB in size, whereas (I believe) AIF files are only supposed to be 2GB or smaller.
- iTunes refuses to play it.
- Logic Pro gives the error message "`party-mix.aif is empty!`" when I try to import it.
- VLC will open and play the file, but it ends after an 1 hour (I guess this is the 2GB point).
- Attempting to transcode using ffmpeg to Ogg gives the errors,

  > `[aiff @ 0x102051000] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5001333`
  >
  > ....
  >
  > `[pcm_s16be @ 0x10205a200] invalid PCM packet`

  but the resulting file plays in VLC up till 1 hour, when it ends.
- Attempting to transcode using ffmpeg to MP3 gives similar results as Ogg, except that the number of channels must reduced from 6 to 2.  This is odd because it was a stereo project - where the extra 4 channels came from I have no idea.
- There are a few places where the audio has been very noticeably sped up.

My question:  how can I transcode this frankenstein monster to MP3 without losing the second half?  I am running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Comment: Closers: While the question might sound off topic, it requires programing and data structure knowledge to resolve.  It's a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

## Break the source file into two target files

This may not be as painful as it sounds.  [AIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) is a really simple format, it should be easy to parse with custom code or even some *nix cli tools on mathematically determined boundaries.

- **Correct parse of file:** Write a simple AIFF parser that can read the frames ("chunk" in AIFF world, I understand) a AIFF file larger than 2GB.  Decide on a frame to cut at, and create two files.
- **Hacky cut-n-tweek:** As long as you cut the file exactly on a frame boundary, you should be able to get the 2nd half clip to play.  Maybe you'll have to pre-pad some header data.

Tools that would be useful in exploring the AIFF format:

- [`hexdump`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_hexdump.htm) (along with `tail` and `head`)
- [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)